# Reducing the size of image (in KBs)

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

M using `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to create a png image from a pdf file.
I want to reduce the size of the image created.

how can it be done??

Comment: another option is to save it as jpeg (I think it doesn't matter because its created out of pdf) with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and set the `compressionQuality`

Comment: okies..i'll try using JPEGRepresentation..

but still there is no way t control the size of PNG??? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving as a JPG with 90% quality will drastically reduce the size and the image will still look OK.
Because of the iPhone's high DPI display, it wouldn't be noticeable at all!

Answer (score -1):

you can load the png into a UIImage  and then resize it.

this coves how to resize it.

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/